# How to interact with program from command line

Tags: bash, command-line

Is there any method to interact with a program directly from the commmand line?

For example, I've a program, `data.o`, which produces a file `mydata.out` and then I want to plot it with `gnuplot`.

I can open the plotting program with `gnuplot &` and then I would like the shell to write somehow in this job/background shell I just opened `plot mydata.out`. (`gnuplot` is just an example, the question would be similar for executing some Macros or Hotkeys in every program I can open from the command line without leaving it).

Comment: you should google about inter-process communication. and also u should go down in programming in linux to understand that ur question is crude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- some programs like gnuplot accept a command file, it may be easier to generate on and then pass it as argument.
- some programs don't depend on interaction, for them piping to stdin may work

  ```
  (
      printf "my command\n"
      printf "my other command line\n"
  ) | theProgram and its args
  ```
- other depend on interaction and mandate that their standard input is a terminal, you have to use `expect` or equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

programs or services that implement d-bus can be interacted from command line or from any other process. https://developer.gnome.org/gio/2.29/gdbus.html and googling about it should give you insight about inter-process communication.